# New Workbook with Date

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a new workbook from a macro that would allow me to place the current date (preferably just the month) into the title of the workbook.  Is such a thing possible, and if so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub New_WB()
Dim WB as Workbook
Set WB = Workbooks.Add
WB.SaveAs "C:/User/Test/WB name " & Format(Date,"mm") & ".xlsx" 'Fill this in with the path and name that you would like
End sub
```

This is the general code. Without more information, I am afraid I cannot give you more specific code. This will give you the two number month (ex "02" for February, use "mmm" if you want "Feb" for February)

Comment: That's really all I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. I just edited the code to make it more accurate. Please let me know if this does not work for your purpose.